# Can I install Ubuntu12.04.2 desktop from my USB on some other computer while it boot?

Tags: boot, usb

My computer is having a booting properly and I have windows XP installed in it so i decided to install ubuntu. Can I do that through the boot manager using a usb stick ???

Comment: If your Mainboard supports booting from USB (check it in your BIOS) than it should work. Here are all the infos: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick (Personally, I would recommend installing it from CD/DVD-ROM because I never had problems with Ubuntu on disc while installing from USB didn't work for me) EDIT: I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: yup,you understood it correctly. but the CD/DVD drive of my laptop isnt working well. So should I go with USB or not ??

Comment: allright, than do it. when you do it like JorgeArturo said it, you really can't break anything. be carefull not to overwrite your windows installation by installing ubuntu on that drive. and if you want to change the boot order (windows first, not ubuntu), this page should help you after the installation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2 Now, good luck and have fun with Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

I installed my ubuntu using the USB method, you should have no problem.

### Here is how to:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

1. First check if you can `live boot` (not install).
2. And if it does work then restart and select the `install option`.

Hope this was helpful :-)